# What kind of object is this or is it even an object? And how does it work?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I'm working on a Dashboard widget and I came across a code that looks like this:

```
var variableName = {
"SomeName":"someValue",
"someName": "another value",
};
```

That's pretty much a sum of what it looks like. My question is what is it, how does it work and what can I do with it? An example would be perfect. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an example right there. It is an object. you use it like any other object `variableName.SomeName`. I don't understand what is the question?

Comment: My question is: why use this instead of declaring an object using a direct instance or a template. There must be a difference between a literal object in it's use other than the fact that it looks different right? I could be wrong

Comment: I don't think there is any real difference. Six or half a dozen ... Its all the same in the long run. (unless you are a baker ;) )

Comment: Okay then, thank you very much sir! I love this website!!!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote people (eg. mike there needs some love). If you have the time and knowledge try to answer a few questions yourself too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's called an *object literal* in JavaScript, it acts more like an enum in most languages.

```
var messageState = {
  new: 0,
  read: 1,
  deleted: 2
};
```

With that in place, you have an easy to read way of determining message state:

```
var message = GetMessage();
if (message.state == messageState.deleted) {
  alert('This message is deleted');
}
```

This is also an easy way to organize functional pieces within your JS file. If you want to only use one JS file for you entire site, which is highly recommended for all kinds of optimization, you can use this instead of writing several different functions:

```
var Message {
  sendMessage: function(msg) {
    // method to send msg
  },

  deleteMessage: function(msg) {
    // method to delete msg
  }
};


var Vote = {
  votePostUp: function(post) {
    // method to vote post up
  },

  votePostDown: function(post) {
    // method to vote post down
  }
};
```

And to call:

```
Message.sendMessage(theMessage);
Vote.votePostUp(myPost);
```

Comment: Okay, this is neat! So I can use it to categorize functions then. That's the best way I can put it in lay man's terms. Still, pretty darn helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely! This is actually a pretty important concept in javascript, because all JSON objects are in this format also, so you should see this format often. I'm glad this helped give an overview!

Answer (score 5):

That's an object literal. It's pretty much just like this:

```
var variableName = new Object();
variableName.SomeName = "someValue";
variableName.someName = "another value";
```

Comment: +1 That description helps bring it home for somebody who's trying to understand object literal in context of what they already know. Great example.

Comment: Thank you! I see how it resembles an object now, but what is the difference other than the way it's declared? Can I do something with this type of object that I can't with a direct instance of an object?

Comment: No, it should be just like `new Object()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of an [*object literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals).

It creates a normal object with two properties.

Comment: This is a valid answer; I don't see why it was downvoted. (+1 to bring it back to zero)

Comment: Probably retaliatory in response to @SLaks correctly pointing out an incorrect answer (now deleted).

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript object created with object literal notation.

You can access its properties like this:

```
variableName["SomeName"];
```

or

```
variableName.SomeName;
```

You can also iterate over the properties of said object (in arbitrary order) with a `for...in` loop:

```
for(var prop in variableName) {
    alert(prop + " = " + variableName[prop]);
}
```

For an excellent guide of working with JavaScript objects, check out [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/User%3aquzi3/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on working with objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is an associative array (a hash map or a dictionary in some languages). Basically it's an array that associates an object with another object, like a word is an associated with its definition in a real dictionary.

It's also JavaScript's main form of objects (they associate function names with function bodies).